# UIWebView supported file types

Tags: ios, uiwebview

Does anyone have an exhaustive list of supported file types for a `UIWebView`? I want to check if a file is be supported before trying to display it.

[The docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/qa/qa1630/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008749) show general cases but I am looking for a list to check against so I don't try to display something I can't. I'd prefer not to have to try every filetype on my own (e.g. for Word .doc is clearly stated, but what about .docx, .docm, etc.). Thanks in advance, links are appreciated!

Answer (score 4):

I've found the result from an article posted in 2012. Not sure whether there are upgrades.

- Excel (.xls)
- Keynote (.key.zip)
- Numbers (.numbers.zip)
- Pages (.pages.zip)
- PDF (.pdf)
- Powerpoint (.ppt)
- Word (.doc)
- Rich Text Format (.rtf)
- Rich Text Format Directory (.rtfd.zip)
- Keynote '09 (.key)
- Numbers '09 (.numbers)
- Pages '09 (.pages)

[UIWebView MIME Types](http://blog.csdn.net/arthurchenjs/article/details/7336303)

Answer (score 0):

These formats are also supported:

- .csv
- .docx
- .xlsx
- .txt

Unfortunately, LibreOffice formats are not supported, even now.